# Basic SQL query for date filter returns error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to do a basic query, but pgadmin returns an error that I don't understang.

So, I'm trying to look into the `date_column` column of the table `schema.tbl` and use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM schema.tbl WHERE date_column > '2022-01-01'
```

It results in an error as follows:

```
ERROR:  column "date_column" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from schema.tbl WHERE date_column > '...
                                                       ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "tbl.date_column".
```

Why do I get this error? The hint doesn't help at all, because searching for "tbl.date_column" instead of date doesn't bring a solution.

I also tried '2022-01-01 00:00:00' which didn't bring the wished result, but the same error:

```
SELECT * FROM schema.tbl
```

Returns the full table and I see that the column `date_column` exists in it.

Edit: adjusted the column_name

Comment: `date` is a poor choice for a field name because it is a [Reserved Word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html). If you want to keep using it then you will need to double quote it `"date"`.

Comment: perhaps `SELECT * FROM schema.tbl WHERE "date" > '2022-01-01'`, as `date` is alsoa data type

Comment: What happened when you tried `where tbl.date > ...`?

Comment: Adjusted column of date name.

Comment: where tbl.date_name returns the same error.

Comment: Can you do a `\d schema.tbl` and post the response? Something isn't adding up here.

Comment: What client are you using to run the query?

Comment: ```ERROR:  syntax error at or near "/"
LINE 1: /dt schema.tbl
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1```

I'm running pgadmin

Comment: `\dt` not `/dt`

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \dt rmv_ers.incidents_ers_prod
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1

Comment: @HeavyBulb the `\dt` command won't work on pgadmin. Try it with `psql`

Comment: While you are in `psql` try your `select` query also.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to psql. I only can use pgadmin and SQL-functions in R.

Comment: 1) Then in `pgAdmin` right click on the table --> Scripts --> CREATE script to get the table definition. 2) What version of `pgAdmin`? 3) What version of Postgres? 4) The OS versions involved? **Add information as update as to question**. FYI, I cannot replicate here on `pgAdmin4 6.3`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but use `to_date('2022-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')` instead of `2022-01-01`. Can you add the script of creating table ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is trivial as pgAdmin wants column names in double-quotation-marks. So, instead of

`SELECT * FROM schema.tbl WHERE date_column > '2022-01-01'`

it's just

`SELECT * FROM schema.tbl WHERE "date_column" > '2022-01-01'`.